# Why is the domain of this trig sub using $\sec$ from 0 to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and from $\pi$ to $\frac{3\pi}{2}$

Tags: calculus

I am looking at this problem:

[image]

and I'm wondering about the domain. Why are we choosing the domain to be 0 to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and from $\pi$ to $\frac{3\pi}{2}$ ?

Comment: Because when $\theta=\frac{\pi} {2} $, $\cos (\tfrac{\pi} {2})=0 $ and we have a $\frac10$ situation?

Comment: But why the domain range? What's wrong with thetas between $\pi/2$ and $\pi$?

Comment: Between $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\pi$, $\cos \theta $ becomes negative and we don't want that under the square root?

Comment: $\cos{theta}$ is negative between $\pi$ and $\frac{3\pi}{2}$ too though

Comment: Any updates on this?